# How to make a loss function in a YOLO architecture?

Tags: python, tensorflow, yolo

I'm working on my own YOLO model and my training yield no result.

My model :

```
def res_block(input, filters, size=2, reduse=False, batchnorm=True) :
    skip = layers.Conv2D(filters, (1,1), padding='same')(input)
    for i in range(size) :
        input = layers.Conv2D(filters, 3, padding='same', activation='leaky_relu')(input)
    input = layers.Add()([input, skip])
    input = layers.BatchNormalization()(input)
    input = layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.05)(input)
    return input

# Entrées
input_img = layers.Input(shape=(IMAGE_SIZE[0], IMAGE_SIZE[1], 3))

x = input_img
x = res_block(x, 64, 2)
x = res_block(x, 64, 2)
x = layers.MaxPooling2D(2)(x)
x = res_block(x, 128, 2)
x = res_block(x, 128, 2)
x = layers.MaxPooling2D(2)(x)
x = res_block(x, 256, 2)
x = res_block(x, 256, 2)
x = layers.MaxPooling2D(2)(x)
x = res_block(x, 256, 2)
x = res_block(x, 256, 2)
x = layers.MaxPooling2D(2)(x)
x = res_block(x, 256, 2)
x = res_block(x, 256, 2)
x = layers.MaxPooling2D(2)(x)
x = res_block(x, 512, 3)

# Sorties
output = layers.Conv2D((5+len(MODEL_CLASSES))*len(MODEL_ARCHOR_BOXES), (1, 1), padding='same')(x)
output = layers.Reshape((MODEL_CELLULES[0], MODEL_CELLULES[1], len(MODEL_ARCHOR_BOXES), 5+len(MODEL_CLASSES)))(output)
```

My loss function :

```
"""
Etape 1 : Séparation des prédictions
"""
# Prédictions
pred_x, pred_y , pred_w, pred_h , pred_conf, pred_classes = tf.split(y_pred, (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, len(MODEL_CLASSES)), axis=-1)

# Vérité terrain
    
true_x , true_y , true_w , true_h , true_conf , true_classes = tf.split(y_true, (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, len(MODEL_CLASSES)), axis=-1)

"""
Etape 2 : Conversion des coordonnées des predictions
"""
converted_pred_x = tf.sigmoid(pred_x)
converted_pred_y = tf.sigmoid(pred_y)
converted_pred_w = tf.exp(pred_w)
converted_pred_h = tf.exp(pred_h)
converted_pred_conf = tf.sigmoid(pred_conf)
converted_pred_classes = tf.math.softmax(pred_classes)

"""
Etape 3 : Calcul des masks
"""

iou = calculate_iou(true_x, true_y, true_w, true_h, converted_pred_x, converted_pred_y, converted_pred_w, converted_pred_h)
obj_mask_ij = true_conf

"""
Etape 4 : Calcul des pertes
"""

# Perte de localisation XY 
errors_xy = tf.square(converted_pred_x - true_x) + tf.square(converted_pred_y- true_y)
errorsloss_xy = errors_xy * obj_mask_ij
loss_xy = tf.reduce_sum(errorsloss_xy, axis = [0,1,2,3,4])


# Perte de localisation WH
errors_wh = tf.square(tf.sqrt(converted_pred_w)- tf.sqrt(true_w)) + tf.square(tf.sqrt(converted_pred_h) - tf.sqrt(true_h))
errorsloss_wh = errors_wh * obj_mask_ij
loss_wh = tf.reduce_sum(errorsloss_wh, axis = [0,1,2,3,4])


# Perte de confiance avec objet
error_conf_obj = tf.square(true_conf - iou * converted_pred_conf)
loss_conf_obj = tf.reduce_sum(error_conf_obj, axis = [0,1,2,3])

# Perte de confiance sans objet
error_conf_noobj = tf.square(true_conf - converted_pred_conf)
loss_conf_noobj = tf.reduce_sum(error_conf_noobj, axis = [0,1,2,3])


# Calculez la perte totale
return loss_xy + loss_wh + loss_conf_obj + loss_conf_noobj
```

Each implementation i found on GitHub uses a different loss function and the YOLOv1,YOLOv2 and YOLOv3 papers can't help me.

My trainings don't really do something and sometimes i have "nan" due to the "tf.exp" in the loss function.